# Getting a particular type of properties from custom Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am trying to iterate through a NSString type properties in my custom class so I can set all the values with its properties name as keys.

Is there anyway to detect isKindOfClass with respect to objc_property_t from class_copyPropertyList?

Also, I have a question about for loop, is there a way to skip a particular iteration? Lets say if my property list is not that kind of class for that particular iteration, how can I skip that iteration and proceed to next iteration where another sub set of properties will be determined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use continue: [Objective-C Looping](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Looping_with_do_and_while_Statements#The_continue_Statement)